# Get the complex object tag name from xml schema in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I would like to ask if there's a way to get the tag names associated to a given "complex type name" (from complex object inside a XSD (XML Schema Definition)) in C# (.NET Framework 4.5).

The result I would like to achieve is: If I search for `WhateverTypeName1` the value `"childoftypeone"` should be returned.

Let's say that we have the following XSD excerpt:

```
<xs:complexType name="ParentType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="childoftypeone" type="WhateverTypeName1"/>
        <xs:element name="childoftypetwo" type="OtherTypeName"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- after some declarations -->

<xs:complexType name="WhateverTypeName1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <!-- other elements from sequence -->
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

From the `XmlSchema` type, I can get a `XmlSchemaComplexObject` by searching for `WhateverTypeName1` this way:

```
var schema = new XmlSchema(); // load the XSD here.

var arr = new string[] { "WhateverTypeName1" };

var type = schema.Items
    .OfType<XmlSchemaObject>()

    // we can search matching the type here, put this way just to be concise
    .Where(w => w.GetType().Name.ToLower().Contains("complex"))
    .Select(s => (XmlSchemaComplexType)s)
    .FirstOrDefault(w => arr.Contains(w.Name));
```

The thing is, from this `XmlSchemaComplexType` object, I didn't manage to match it with the `"childoftypeone"` tag declaration on the `ParentType` (`<xs:element name="childoftypeone" type="WhateverTypeName1"/>`).

I only managed to get this pairing, if I search for its parent object (`ParentType`) and walk through its `Particle` property. However, I guess it's not possible to get where this type is being used (e.g. the `ParentType`) from its own `XmlSchemaComplexType`

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I developed a kind of a recursive search method to get what I needed, since I didn't manage to find anything inside of `System.Xml` namespace that would give me anything near what I've achieved.

It's a quite basic/unoptimized code, and I didn't test it extensively, but it works. It returns a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` where the keys are names of the types inside the XSD file (which are the class names from the .cs file generated by `XSD.exe` as well) and the tags where these types are used.

Here it follows:

```
public Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> GetTagsByType(
    ICollection<XmlSchemaObject> schemaObjects)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

    var xmlElements = schemaObjects
        .Where(w => w.GetType() == typeof(XmlSchemaElement))
        .ToArray();

    var types = schemaObjects
        .Where(w => w.GetType() == typeof(XmlSchemaComplexType))
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var item in xmlElements)
    {
        var el = (XmlSchemaElement)item;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Name) ||
            el.SchemaTypeName == null ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(el.SchemaTypeName.Name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (!result.ContainsKey(el.SchemaTypeName.Name))
        {
            result.Add(el.SchemaTypeName.Name, new HashSet<string> { el.Name });
        }
        else
        {
            result[el.SchemaTypeName.Name].Add(el.Name);
        }
    }

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var t = (XmlSchemaComplexType)type;

        if (t.Particle == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var isSubClassOfGroupBase = t.Particle.GetType()
            .IsSubclassOf(typeof(XmlSchemaGroupBase));

        if (!isSubClassOfGroupBase)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var items = ((XmlSchemaGroupBase)t.Particle)
            .Items
            .OfType<XmlSchemaObject>()
            .ToArray();

        var res = GetTagsByType(items);

        foreach (var item in res.Keys)
        {
            if (result.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                foreach (var r in res[item])
                {
                    result[item].Add(r);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(item, res[item]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```